# Encounter UnsupportedClassVersionError on log4j2's dependencies when CDI is enabled

Tags: cdi, log4j2, unsupported-class-version

I don't have any UnsupportedClassVersionError on log4j2's dependency(LMAX Disruptor) until CDI is enabled(beans.xml). The UnsupportedClassVersionError tells to run on java9 instead of java8, but this is not an optional. Please advise how to avoid this error on java8.

Weblogic 12.2
log4j 2.11.2

```
<May 15, 2019 10:50:00,579 AM SGT> <Error> <Class Loaders> <BEA-2162500> <Class, module-info, was compiled with an incompatible version of Java. Ensure that all the classes needed by the application have been compiled with a compatible java version. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: module-info has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: module-info has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<May 15, 2019 10:50:00,964 AM SGT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "6752224278283" for task "4" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:com/lmax/disruptor/ExceptionHandler"
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:com/lmax/disruptor/ExceptionHandler
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:95)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lmax.disruptor.ExceptionHandler
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclude log4j2 CDI scan as below:

beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <scan>
        <!-- Prevent java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lmax/disruptor -->
        <exclude name="org.apache.logging.**" />
    </scan>
</beans>
```